# How to fill a textbox of another domain, from my domain?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can i insert a value to another domain (not have access to this domain)  textbox, from filling a form from my domain?

Form in my domain:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="birthdaysend">
 <input type="text" value="" name="birthday" >
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Where this value will be shown in the other domain textbox (where i do not have access)

```
<form action="" method="post" name="birthdayreceive">
 <input type="text" value="" name="birthdaydate" >
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When i fill birthday date from my form, on submit the same date to be shown in this other textbox where i do not have access.

Comment: I can say create a get of the text in the textbox and send it to the other domain, the domain gets the $_GET and then add it to the text box.

Comment: Impossible without control of other server

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the other domain is your visitor's online banking and that the text box is where you put the account number to transfer money to.

Now, for obvious security reasons, what you want it entirely impossible.

Comment: I'm not sure this is as obvious as you claim. If I can automagically log into their banking when they visit my site, then presumably I can also store their details, and manually visit the bank website later. It being "entirely impossible" with js doesn't improve security as far as I can see.

Comment: @OllieFord — If it can fill in the place where you send sending money to, then it can submit the form too, and then it can transfer money to wherever the JS likes.

Answer (score 0):

After you received your own form from your server, you need to mimic a browser to request the page from other domain, and submit that form using your own code.

One example I think is [cURL extension](http://www.paulund.co.uk/make-cross-domain-ajax-calls-with-jquery-and-php)

> PHP can post data to other domains by using the cURL extension

Comment: please could you send me an example, is very difficult for me to get the point how to get this done

Comment: [Try this way](http://www.paulund.co.uk/make-cross-domain-ajax-calls-with-jquery-and-php)

Answer (score 0):

On form submit, you could get a $_GET or turn the $_POST into a $_GET,

Send the $_GET to another domain like

www.otherdomain.com/index.php?textbox=

then from the textbox on the other domain

```
<textarea><?php echo $_GET['textbox']; ?></textarea>
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_GET['textbox']; ?>" />
```

Im not really for sure what your trying to accomplish, I hope this gives you and idea to what exactly im getting at here. Or my other result is to use cURL, so the other domain can get the information from the other server.

Comment: The OP said: "(I do) *not have access to this domain*"